# docker runtime issue file not found

Tags: docker, exec

I have created a docker to run PIVX coin in it. I can see the files are in the docker.

```
$ sudo docker exec -i ff6438b86a55 ls /usr/local/bin
pivx-cli
pivx-tx
pivxd
```

But when I run `sudo docker exec -i ff6438b86a55 pivx-cli` :

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"pivx-cli\": executable file not
>   found in $PATH": unknown

The docker is running and it seems the pivxd daemon is running.

```
$ sudo docker exec -i ff6438b86a55 ps fax
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
6   ?        Rs     0:00 ps fax
1   pts/0    Ss+    0:00 tail -f /dev/null /usr/local/bin/pivxd
```

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in your path? What makes you say the pivxd daemon is running?

Comment: It appears in ps fax

Comment: The only thing `ps` shows is a running tail command in pid 1, no `pivxd` daemon is running. You do appear to be tailing your binary, so the container logs are likely unreadable. You also forgot to answer whether `/usr/local/bin` is in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the executables have exec privs and Try

```
sudo docker exec -it ff6438b86a55 /usr/local/bin/pivx-cli
```

Comment: Ive tried with full path /usr/local/bin/pivx-clivsame errorbut same error